# how to specify the stream for juju when run juju metadata generate-tools command?

Tags: juju

all

I am using juju in my private cloud . use OpenStack as cloud management software .

When I read docs about juju , I know , there is a metadata should generated for tools .

I can run this command successfully , with some question in mind , one of them is as below:

```
$ juju metadata generate-tools -d /home/john/juju
No stream specified, defaulting to released tools in the releases directory.
Finding tools in /home/john/juju for stream released.
```

---

How to assign stream to above command ? 
There are always a tips told me I should specify the stream , any suggestions?

Comment: Check this site it may help you https://jujucharms.com/docs/1.20/howto-privatecloud

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Juju bootstraps a cloud, it needs two critical pieces of information:

The uuid of the image to use when starting new compute instances.
The URL from which to download the correct version of a tools tarball.
This necessary information is stored in a json metadata format called "simplestreams".
For supported public cloud services such as Amazon Web Services, HP Cloud, Azure, etc, no action is required by the end user. However, those setting up a private cloud, or who want to change how things work (eg use a different Ubuntu image), can create their own metadata, after understanding a bit about how it works.

Assume an Apache http server with base URL https://juju-metadata, providing access to information at `<base>/images` and `<base>/tools`. The Juju environment yaml file could have the following entries (one or both):

```
tools-metadata-url: https://juju-metadata/tools
image-metadata-url: https://juju-metadata/images
```

The required files in each location is as per the directory layout described earlier. For a shared directory, use a URL of the form "file:///sharedpath".

try this now

```
juju metadata generate-tools -d /home/john/juju
```

Comment: _Excellent answer_ man!